# ¿Como puedo utilizar los resultados de las funciones con apuntadores que declaro?

Tags: c, funciones, punteros, puntero-a-función

Si saben donde puedo encontrar información para entender como utilizar las funciones de manera correcta se los agradecería mucho.
 Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Saludos

```
/*Programa que calcule el producto escalar entre dos vectores

Mi funcion principal */

int main(){

    int v1[2],v2[2];

    IntroduceVector(v1);
    LeerVector(v1);
    Modulos(v1);
    IntroduceVector(v2);
    LeerVector(v2);
    Modulos(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

Mi primera funcion para que el usuario introduzca los valores del vector

```
 void IntroduceVector(int *a){
         int i;
         for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            printf("Introduce un valor para la posicion %i del vector 1: ",i+1);
            scanf("%i",(a+i)); //Guardamos en la locacalidad de memoria
         }
 }

 void LeerVector(int *a){
    int i;      
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            printf("%i, ",*(a+i)); //Vemos el dato del vector
    }   
}
```

De esta ultima función que sigue quiero utilizar el resultado de Rv1 para realizar el producto escalar en la función main. ¿Como puedo utilizar ese resultado o que tengo que cambiar para utilizarla?
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
void Modulos (int *a){

     float Rv1;
            Rv1 = ( sqrt( (pow(a[0],2)) +  (pow(a[1],2))       ));
         printf("El modulo del primer vector es: %.2f\n",Rv1);

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? El código parece funcionar.

Comment: En lugar de `void`, retorna el resultado en cuestión para recogerlo en otra variable desde el punto en que sea llamada. Por otro lado, quizás no deberías tener esos `printf()` dentro de las funciones. La misión de una función es realizar un cálculo y retornar lo que ha salido como resultado, en lugar de imprimirlo. Es el programa que invoca la función quien decide qué hacer con el resultado (imprimirlo o usarlo en otro cálculo posterior, o incluso volcarlo a un fichero si fuera necesario)